# angular-nvd3 how to change the chart background color

Tags: angular-nvd3

I am following the angular-nvd3 example, and want to change the background color of the chart . I looked at this http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart
but i don't see anywhere you can set the background color. any help?
btw, my plot looks like this with black background.[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems problems are solved. after including the "nv.d3.css", everything renders correctly

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.1/nv.d3.min.css"/>
```

add it to your index.html

Comment: This solved the problem for me but still I want to be able to change the background color. Did you manage to find out how to do it?